# How to sort alphanumeric values in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

I'm currently building a program and am wondering how to sort a alphanumerical list like the one below, based on smallest to biggest number.

```
array1 = ["14f","9c","2d","7a"]
```

I would just like the numbers to sort like this ["2d","7a","9c","14f"]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can turn it to a list of numbers by turning each string to it's hex value, then sorting a list of numbers is a well known problem.

Comment: Is this a hex value? i.e. if the list is `['1ff', '2a']`, which one goes first?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sorted` with a custom `key` function in order to sort the list:

```
import re
sorted(array1, key = lambda x: int(re.search(r'\d+', x)[0]))
# ['2d', '7a', '9c', '14f']
```

Where this custom `key` function is extracting the number within each string using `re.search`:

```
[int(re.search(r'\d+', i)[0]) for i in array1] 
# [14, 9, 2, 7]
```